# Get in input from another windows form in c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows forms application and I need to get an input from user. I decided to use another form. The code in my main windows form like that :

```
inputPage p = new inputPage();
p.Visible = true;
VBand = p.getValueDouble();
```

My second form ( where I get the input from the user ) is simple. It contains only a label, textbox and ok button.
My problem is, I want to call getValueDouble function (3rd line of the code above) after when we are sure that user enter the value and press the ok button. So how can I do this?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the Form's `ShowDialog()` method.  This will cause your current function to wait until the user clicks the button to close the form.

```
inputPage p = new inputPage();

DialogResult result = p.ShowDialog();

if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    VBand = p.getValueDouble();
}
```

The OK button on the form should have its `DialogResult` property set to `DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: it seems true if I write DialogResult.Cancel instead of Ok

Comment: @dnur : In your 2nd form, set the "Ok" button to be the "Ok" action, and the "Cancel" button to be the "Cancel" action.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your inputPage is a form:

```
inputPage p = new inputPage();
if(p.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
{
   VBand = p.getValueDouble();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't give an error but program doesn't sense that I pressed the ok button

Answer (score 0):

Please watch the naming conventions: Class names should start with capital letters, as well as method names.

You should do the following:

```
InputPage p = new InputPage();
if (p.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    vBand = p.GetValueDouble();
}
```

When using WPF, this looks as follows:

```
InputPage p = new InputPage();
p.Owner = this;
if (p.ShowDialog() ?? false)
{
    ....
}
```

In WPF, the `ShowDialog`  method returns a `bool?` value that can either be `null` or `false` (dialog was cancelled or otherwise closed without a user selection) or `true` if the user pressed OK.

The `if (... ?? ...)` could be rewritten to:

```
bool? ret = p.ShowDialog(); 
if (ret.HasValue() && ret)
{
}
```